# Connection timeout sequelize on AWS Lambda on third party MYSQL

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have deployed my lambda function via Serverless framework. When i invoke the function locally it works fine. But on AWS Lambda environment it is unable to make connection to MYSQL which is hosted on remotemysql.com. It gives timeout error every time.

Tried to increase timeout but nothing works

```
sequelize = new Sequelize(
    process.env.DB_NAME,
    process.env.DB_USER,
    process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    {
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        dialect: "mysql",
        logging: false,
        connectTimeout: 60000
    }
);

sequelize
    .authenticate()
    .then(() => {
        logger.info("Database connection established");
        // do my work
        // some api calls to xys hosts outside servers
    })
    .catch(error => {
        logger.error("Database connection failed", {
            code: error.original.code,
            errno: error.original.errno
        });
        process.exit(1);
    });
```

My function is not inside any VPC and it has internet access allowed as I verified it is returning API responses which I am making to some other services outside AWS.

I am not sure if it is because of TCP connection or something else.

Please advise

Comment: Can you share how do you define DB_HOST ?

Comment: I have tried `remotemysql.com` as well as `37.59.55.185` both works fine from my local invocation.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the database code and see if this still happens? Could be a permission problem.

Comment: @Madeo which kind of permission ? Except database everything works fine. Its just database connection timeout

Comment: Are you sure lambda can connect to internet ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I have figured out what was causing the issue. It was not because of the connectivity but something wrong with the async handler.

my handler was like

```
exports.handler = async () => { ... }
```

I removed `async` and now it is working fine.

Comment: Quite sure that was **not** the problem. Probably you were not returning the function, but it is hard to say without seeing the entire code.

Comment: Can you explain what is wrong with async ? As it was followed from documentation. I am still not clear with the reason. Thanks

Comment: From the Cloudwatch logs can you clearly see that the timeout is from Sequelize? Because I suspect that is coming from lambda. Could you please post all the code?